# I can't connect to the Oracle server using SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

when I installed oracle 11g and SQL developer it worked properly and after some times I have disabled an oracle startup using third-party software and I can't find what happened now I can't connect to my server now.
I'm using Windows OS

> the error when I open my oracle XE using the browser
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950
> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080.

when I open my SQL developer and  try to connect

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

> Listener refused the connection with the following error:
> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

> Vendor code 12505

Comment: As you disabled it, did you enable it back? At least both Oracle (database) service and Oracle Listener should be started.

Comment: yeah I have to know what I need to enable cause it was automatically disabled by third-party software

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32009/strt_stp.htm#UNXAR002) first. No need to copy it here to include all the possibilities. Also you can check this article: [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question has nothing about any programming since your database is not even started or accessible.

Comment: This is not a programming question and is not even a problem with SQL Developer. You need to find what was disabled and restart it so that there is something to connect to. We cannot help with that because you have not given any details on the services that are running or even which operating system you are using (so we can't even tell you where to look).

Comment: I'm using windows